# Subclass instance recorder in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented

I've written a relatively small abstract class in Java which keeps track of all instances of it's sublasses. Any class which extends this abstract class will automatically have all its instances stored (via a weak reference) in a Set, which can be retrieved if a subclass ever wants to get references to all it's instances.

Although this class is relatively short and simple, I have never made anything like it and so I want to ensure that I'm not doing something terribly wrong or giving in to any bad practices:

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class InstanceRecorder {
    private static Map<Class<? extends InstanceRecorder>, Set<InstanceRecorder>> instances;

    static {
        instances = new HashMap<>();
    }

    {
        instances.putIfAbsent(this.getClass(), Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<>()));
        instances.get(this.getClass()).add(this);
    }

    protected static int countInstances(Class<? extends InstanceRecorder> key) {
        if (instances.containsKey(key))
            return instances.get(key).size();
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected static <T extends InstanceRecorder> Set<T> getInstances(Class<T> key) {
        if (instances.containsKey(key))
            return Collections.unmodifiableSet((Set<T>) instances.get(key));
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

As I said above, I've never made a class like this before and so any feedback or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of when you think this might be useful?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1

Comment: @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ, You're correct - It says "Do not add an improved version of the code." My mistake.

Comment: @forsvarir, I was imagining that this would be useful in cases where a programmer would want to call an instance method or change the value of an instance variable on  all instances of a certain class. The programmer could, of course, simply use an array for this task, however this class stores instances automatically and also illuminates the risk of a memory leak as it utilizes weak references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two very small details:

Instead of using `putIfAbsent` / `get`, you can use the single function `computeIfAbsent`:

```
instances.computeIfAbsent(
    this.getClass(),
    ign -> Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<>())
).add(this);
```

Instead of a `new HashSet` for a not-found-result, you can simply return `Collections.emptySet()`. As your return value is immutable anyway this is more consistent and does not create an additional object for nothing.

(And just to give another opinion: I prefer not to have braces around single statements - only so that you know there is no unambiguos truth out there :-))

Comment: Yes, this makes the code look far cleaner, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Your code is not thread-safe. You should use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap`, if this code is ever run in a multithreaded environment.

In Java 8 there was a [terrible performance bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161372) in `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent`, which would lock the whole map even if the key already exists. That bug has been fixed in Java 9. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481796/concurrenthashmap-computeifabsent/26483476).

Comment: I completely forgot about Thread safety! Nice catch

Answer (score 3):

in my opinion, the code is good, but I have some suggestions.

1. Instead of using `java.util.Map#containsKey`, you can directly use `java.util.Map#get` and check if the value is null.

```java
protected static int countInstances(Class<? extends InstanceRecorder> key) {
   Set<InstanceRecorder> instanceRecorders = instances.get(key);

   if (instances != null) 
      return instanceRecorders.size();

   return 0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected static <T extends InstanceRecorder> Set<T> getInstances(Class<T> key) {
   Set<InstanceRecorder> instanceRecorders = instances.get(key);

   if (instanceRecorders != null)
      return Collections.unmodifiableSet((Set<T>) instanceRecorders);

   return new HashSet<>();
}
```

2. In my opinion, it's a bad practice not to put the braces when you have a single instruction coupled with `if`, `while`, `for`, etc. This can make the code harder to read and can cause confusion.